# Default column value in ms access switch statement

Tags: ms-access

how to do this in ms access using switch statement?

```
Select CASE col1 
          when '-' then 'Not Specified'
          else col1
       END
```

In my understanding it should be smth like this

```
SELECT 
  switch(col1  = '-', 'Not Specified', 
         true,  col1 )
```

or

```
SELECT 
  switch(col1  = '-', 'Not Specified', 
         col1  <> '-',  col1 )
```

However this does not seem to work.

maybe there is an alternative way to do this? What I am trying to achieve here is I would like to replace all '-' values in the data set with some custom text and leave other values unchanged.

I need to be using MS ACCESS SQL only and VBA is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured out myself

```
SELECT 
  switch(col1  = '-', 'Not Specified', 
         false,  col1 )
```

this seems to do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `replace` like this:

```
update tablename
set columnname = replace( columnName, instr('-',chr(42)), 'STRING_TO_REPLACE_WITH' )
```